# Error in connecting to Orient DB via JDBC Drivers

Tags: java, jdbc, orientdb

I am trying to connect to Orient DB running in Distributed mode and I am getting following error

> Exception in thread "main" com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OSerializationException:
>   Error on unmarshalling field 'members' in record #-1:-1 with value:

I am using :

```
OrientDB Version: orientdb-community-1.7-rc and 
JDBC Version: OrientDB JDBC Driver 1.7-rc2-SNAPSHOT ALL
```

Below is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {            
    Class.forName("com.orientechnologies.orient.jdbc.OrientJdbcDriver");
    Connection connection = (OrientJdbcConnection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:orient:remote:localhost/VANET", "root", "*****");
}
```

database "VANET" as per the DB connection String above, is present in OrientDB and I able to access and create classes in VANET using OrientDB Studio.

I have already referred to and tried code as [per](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb-jdbc). But no luck yet.

Please help me resolve this issue.

A little more details about the error I am getting

```
Exception in thread "main" com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OSerializationException: Error on unmarshalling field 'members' in record #-1:-1 with value: 
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.orientechnologies.common.log.OLogManager.exception(OLogManager.java:162)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.serialization.serializer.record.string.ORecordSerializerSchemaAware2CSV.fromString(ORecordSerializerSchemaAware2CSV.java:543)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.serialization.serializer.record.string.ORecordSerializerStringAbstract.fromStream(ORecordSerializerStringAbstract.java:80)
    at 
... * <I removed these lines >* ...
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.jdbc.OrientJdbcConnection.<init>(OrientJdbcConnection.java:49)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.jdbc.OrientJdbcDriver.connect(OrientJdbcDriver.java:46)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
    at org.poc.orientdb.jdbc.OrientJDBC.main(OrientJDBC.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.ORecordSchemaAwareAbstract.getSchemaClass(ORecordSchemaAwareAbstract.java:82)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.serialization.serializer.record.string.ORecordSerializerSchemaAware2CSV.fromString(ORecordSerializerSchemaAware2CSV.java:445)
    ... 28 more
```

Comment: Any chance to get the server-side exception if any? Take a look at server console or log/ files

Comment: Thanks for replying. I checked server logs, it just shows a warning every time I try to connect  `[OServer]
2014-02-28 10:41:43:241 WARN Current implementation of storage does not support sbtree collections [ODatabaseRecordAbstract$1]`. I am not sure whether the WARN server log is the reason of the Java side error I am getting. Please advise.

Comment: I have kept the whole log file at below location. In case required, then please refer. [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByFX5A8eYJ7vamR5VzhZN0FaRmM/edit?usp=sharing)